# What are the units for the force output by nstfout, the velocity output by nstvout, and the coordinates output by nstxout in gromacs?

Tags: simulated-data, gromacs

What are the units of force, velocity, and coordinates output by gromacs trajectory? In `.mdp`, they are specified by `nstfout`,`nstvout`,`nstxout`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nstxout`, `nstvout` and `nstfout` are the number of **steps** between coordinates, speed and forces written in the output trajectory ([Output control documentation](https://manual.gromacs.org/current/user-guide/mdp-options.html?highlight=nstxout#output-control)).

As for the units present in your trajectory files (say a `.trr`):
coordinates are in **nm**, speeds in **nm.μs⁻¹** (so in **mm.m⁻¹**) and forces in **kJ.mol⁻¹.nm⁻¹**. These should be consistent through all GROMACS files ([Definitions and Units documentation](https://manual.gromacs.org/current/reference-manual/definitions.html)).

Note that `.xtc` files multiply coordinates by 1000 to compress them, so they are stored in **pm** (see [GROMACS xtc documentation](https://manual.gromacs.org/current/reference-manual/file-formats.html#xtc)). Given [MDAnalysis documentation](https://userguide.mdanalysis.org/1.0.0/formats/reference/xtc.html) on the subject, I believe `.xtc` files can *only* store coordinates, no speeds or forces.

I would be wary of softwares used to analyze your trajectory results (MDAnalysis, VMD, etc), as they may automatically do the conversion of these units, and for example show you coordinates in Å.

Comment: This was a great answer O.Laprevote! We have a [few unanswered GROMACS questions here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gromacs?tab=Unanswered), are you able to help us out at all with those? I'm trying to help take care of the unanswered queue.